# Oracle Enterprise Manager Keystore vs Weblogic Keystore

Tags: weblogic11g, oracle-service-bus, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am having to consume a web service via 2 way SSL. We have exchanged certificates and I am trying to connect and am getting a handshake failure. I am using Oracle Service Bus to connect to the web service. My questions:

1. What is the keystore in the fwmconfig folder (that I access from Oracle Enterprise Manager)?
2. What is the keystore in the weblogic server (that I access from the admin console/managed server keystore tab)?
3. What are the differences between these and which one should I use to import the servers cert and try to connect?
4. Also, there are cacerts in several directories in the installation, what do I use those for?

Not knowing where to import the server certificate. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

1. The enterprise manager keystore is used by fusion middleware for message level security (encrypting the message with certificates
2. The weblogic keystore is used by the webserver/load balancer to accept the HTTP requests and handles SSL
3. See above
4. The cacerts are the default trusted Root CA's

So the keystore to use for enabling SSL is the weblogic server version.
Also be sure to enable 2 way SSL in weblogic:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/security/ConfigureTwowaySSL.html

Resources used:
http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=2059